# Getting indexes of a duplicate neighbour element in R vectors

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function which will have **a numeric vector** **"x"** on input and will create on output a **numeric vector** of xi **indexes**, such that x(i) == x(i+1)

By far I wrote such function neighbor:

```
neighbor <- function(l) {
   stopifnot(is.numeric(l))
   w <- sapply(l, function(x) which(l[x]==l[x+1]))
   w
}
```

**So executing this instruction:**

neighbor(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0))

**Should produce a numeric vector:**

1, 4, 5, 7, 9

But I cannot get it working. Any ideas?

I am searching for an elegant solution without control-flow and if-else instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff` will help with this:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
which(diff(x) == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working like a charm. I will accept it when possible.